# How to create a plugin in android which offers localisation when we included this to some other app

Tags: android, android-layout

I wants to create a plug-in type of thing in android, which currently support 4-5 languages. When I apply this plugin to any project then that project will support these languages.

I don't want to define project specific language support for my each project, my needs is just to use that plugin and enjoy the localisation(plugin will contain translation API to get the desired language). I'm not sure if it is feasible in android or not, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use localized string resources if you want to achieve what I think you are saying, unless you are getting all your strings from an API in the specific language for each user.